# Need a unity3d swarm generator script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple game where lots of flying and walking insects attack a player, and he has to shoot like mad to stay alive.

I want them to attack together in varying attack patterns as group, like a swarm of bees, or like the way jet fighters attack in formation.

Does anybody know of any script out there or something in the asset store that can do it?

I saw this one at the link below, but i'm not sure if it can do the job as i cant get any response from the author.

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/40529

Has some live demos.

anybody has any ideas?

Comment: Requests for scripts are not on topic for this website.

Comment: Also, if you're looking to implement a basic version of this yourself, consider reading up on Boid behaviour - it makes for some very cool flock/swarm effects, and isn't that complicated.

Answer (score 0):

[This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/3hst9l/best_unity_assets_by_keijiro_takahashi_including/) links to a [KvantSwarm](https://github.com/keijiro/KvantSwarm) which may be one way to approach it. You may also want to take a look at their [flocking wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Flocking) for some code that you can drop in and test right away.

[Infrared5](http://blog.infrared5.com/2011/09/airial-combat-in-video-games-a-k-a-dog-fighting/) posted a blog on swarming done for an aerial dogfight.

Comment: I look at both, but i wanted something more like an attack pattern that follows and attacks the player, but in a formation sort of, or a swarm.

Comment: Take a look at this Infrared5 blog and see if that's anything like what you are after.